# For loop for generating multiple statements from a source data file and a template

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to automate my work, where there is a template xlsx file of a monthly statement and a source data file in xlsx.

My first trial is like this:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

path = r"/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx"
os.chdir(path)

workbook_template = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
sheet_result = workbook_template['Statement']

df = pd.read_excel("/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/Data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0)

to_include = "Y"

client_names = df.query('To_choose == @to_include')['client']
num_of_clicks = df.query('To_choose == @to_include')['Net']
fee_to_pay = df.query('To_choose == @to_include')['Fee']

for name in client_names:
    template_client_title = sheet_result['B6']
    date = sheet_result['G6']
    template_client_title.value = name
    date.value = "31/12/2022"
    
    workbook_template.save(f"Statement as of 31 Dec 2022 of {name}.xlsx")
```

For this I have got a error of `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Then I have done some research and tried to use a `With` method and need a context manager. My amended codes as follow:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

path = r"/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx"
os.chdir(path)

workbook_template = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
sheet_result = workbook_template['Statement']

df = pd.read_excel("/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/Data.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0)

to_include = "Y"

client_names = df.query('To_choose == @to_include')['client']
num_of_clicks = df.query('To_choose == @to_include')['Net']
fee_to_pay = df.query('To_choose == @to_include')['Fee']

class load_temp_workbook:
    def __enter__(self):
        load_workbook('template.xlsx')
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return

for name in KOL_names:
    template__title = sheet_result['B6']
    date = sheet_result['G6']
    with load_temp_workbook() as wt:
        template_client_title.value = name
        date.value = "31/12/2022"
        wt.save(f"IB Statement as of 31 Dec 2022 of {name}.xlsx")
```

Then I have got another error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: You have to `return` the workbook in `__enter__`: `return load_workbook('template.xlsx')`. In your first attempt you could just move lines `workbook_template = load_workbook('template.xlsx')` and `sheet_result = workbook_template['Statement']` into the scope of the `for`-loop.

Comment: I have tried both of your solutions, which all work! Much appreciated to your answers thanks!